# Locate an element text by XPath

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using Webdriver in Ruby and I want to locate an element by its xpath, below is an example html:

```
<li id="ID1">
    <label for="accountNumber"> &nbsp;</label>
    123456
    <span id="accountNumber"></span>
</li>
```

How do I get 123456 by xpath or ID?

I have tried below and it does not work:

```
element = driver.find_element :xpath => "//li[@id='ID1']/"
puts element.text
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does `puts element.text` print?

Comment: Did you try //li[contains(@id, 'ID') and contains(text(),"yourtexthere")]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `cssselector` over `xpath` since there are numerous advantages. However, there are certain situations where you can only use `xpath` like selecting parent element, selecting by text etc. In your case you can certainly get away with `cssselector`

Css for your html would be `li#ID1>label[for='accountNumber']` or just simply `label[for='accountNumber']`

If you insist on xpath, it should be `.//li[@id='ID1']/label[@for='accountNumber']` 
or by text 
`.//li[@id='ID1']/label[text()='123456']`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I tried both css and xpath as you suggested and I still can't locate it. Maybe because 123456 is not actually enclosed by tag label?@nilesh

Comment: Those selectors are correct. Do you have more than one elements matching the selector? Are these elements visible? Is this inside an iframe? Is your site publicly available to test this out?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

"//li[contains(.,'123456')]"
or
"//li[@id='ID1']"

In both cases I was able to the get the text '123456' from the text nested inside the element.

Tested code in C#:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void FindByText()
    {
        IWebElement li = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[contains(.,'123456')]")); //Returns correct element
        li = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[@id='ID1']")); //Also returns correct element

        string text = li.Text; //Result: "  123456"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following, it's working for me:

```
element = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//li[@id='ID1']")
puts element.text
```