# How to access the link by searching its text in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a HTML File hierarchy in tree structure in a web page 
as shown in picture.

[image]

The HTML code is

```
<div class="rtMid rtSelected">
    < span class="rtSp"/>
    < img class="rtImg" alt="Automation" src="http://192.168.1.6/eprint_prod_3.8/images/StoreImages/close_folder.png"/>
    < span class="rtIn" title="Automation">Automation (1)</span>
</div>
```

In Selenium  WebDriver is there a way to click on the  `Automation (1)` link by searching only the text I don't want to use XPath reason is the location will be changing so is there a way to find it by its text and click on it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Locate an element text by XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236531/locate-an-element-text-by-xpath)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath is powerful, you found it's unreliable you are not using it right. Spend some time at [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/) please.

This is a simple solution to your question, but there could be many other things you need to think about. E.g. matching title and text, etc.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[text()='Automation (1)']")).click();
```

CSS selector is also powerful and faster, more readable than XPath. But in your case, it doesn't support find by text.

Comment: can u suggest a code i tried 
    driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Automation")).click();

Comment: @Santhosh.S: Make sure this only matches one element. If there are other elements with same text, you need provide more HTML. Answer above provides **exact** match.

Comment: @Santhosh.S: No, it's not the complete code. You need provide HTML for all folder nodes. But try extact match first, if not working, debug for why.

Answer (score 0):

searching by title worked well

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@title,'Automation')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

2 Approaches

Approach 1:

By Class Name:

Here we are having class Name for the Text Automation (1) that is rtIn.
Perform driver.findElement(By.className("rtIn")).click();

Approach 2:

By CSS Selector of Parent and Class Name

CSS Selector of Parent:.rtSelected

WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".rtSelected"))
element1.className("rtIn").click();

Approach 3:

By Direct CSS Selector: 
1. .rtIn
2.  .rtSelected > .rtIn

It is better to use the second CSS Selector

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".rtSelected > .rtIn")).click();